# DAX encode Arabic URL using string substitutions

Tags: powerbi, dax, urlencode

In Power BI, I have this URL in a column:

[http://mubasher.aljazeera.net/news/شاهد-مظاهرات-بميدان-التحرير-ومحافظات-مصرية-عدة-تطالب-برحيل-السيسي](http://mubasher.aljazeera.net/news/%D8%B4%D8%A7%D9%87%D8%AF-%D9%85%D8%B8%D8%A7%D9%87%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D8%A8%D9%85%D9%8A%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%86-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AA%D8%AD%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%B1-%D9%88%D9%85%D8%AD%D8%A7%D9%81%D8%B8%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D9%85%D8%B5%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%A9-%D8%B9%D8%AF%D8%A9-%D8%AA%D8%B7%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A8-%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%AD%D9%8A%D9%84-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D9%8A%D8%B3%D9%8A)

How can I turn it into this?

http%3A%2F%2Fmubasher.aljazeera.net%2Fnews%2F%25D8%25B4%25D8%25A7%25D9%2587%25D8%25AF-%25D9%2585%25D8%25B8%25D8%25A7%25D9%2587%25D8%25B1%25D8%25A7%25D8%25AA-%25D8%25A8%25D9%2585%25D9%258A%25D8%25AF%25D8%25A7%25D9%2586-%25D8%25A7%25D9%2584%25D8%25AA%25D8%25AD%25D8%25B1%25D9%258A%25D8%25B1-%25D9%2588%25D9%2585%25D8%25AD%25D8%25A7%25D9%2581%25D8%25B8%25D8%25A7%25D8%25AA-%25D9%2585%25D8%25B5%25D8%25B1%25D9%258A%25D8%25A9-%25D8%25B9%25D8%25AF%25D8%25A9-%25D8%25AA%25D8%25B7%25D8%25A7%25D9%2584%25D8%25A8-%25D8%25A8%25D8%25B1%25D8%25AD%25D9%258A%25D9%2584-%25D8%25A7%25D9%2584%25D8%25B3%25D9%258A%25D8%25B3%25D9%258A

I understand Excel has an [ENCODEURL](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/DAX-Commands-and-Tips/DAX-to-escape-Arabic-URL/m-p/855466/highlight/true#M6818) function but it's not usable in Power BI.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Uri.EscapeDataString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/uri-escapedatastring) M function to encode special characters according to the rules of [RFC 3986](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc3986/).

If your column is named `URL_Column`, then in Power Query Editor add a custom column using formula like this:

```
= Uri.EscapeDataString([URL_Column])
```

It will encode the data in the column and give you the requested result:

[image]

Comment: Any way to do this with DAX?